# Is there a way of converting polygon vertices to points using GDAL python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, gdal, geometry, geometry-conversion

I have an ArcGIS standard license and I want to convert polygon vertexes to points in a script.  Since I don't have a good enough ArcGIS license I've been using ET Geowizards to get the points.  The problem is you can't run ET Geowizards in python without having the full license.  So I was curious if any other open source geo tools can do this in python, specifically GDAL.  Is it worth looking into this for a solution?

Comment: I have also found this post that might help answer your question: [http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73666/python-gdal-polygon-to-point-shape-file](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73666/python-gdal-polygon-to-point-shape-file)

Comment: note that GDAL has nothing to do with the processing of polygons: it is an image processing library. If you don't like the existing solutions with OGR, which is good, then you can do it with arcpy.da.SearchCursor.